# simple.data orm: how to get max value?

Tags: simple.data

I am using simple.data orm. try to get the max value from the table. couldn't get it work.

```
var latestVersion = _db.AMBest.Version.Max();
```

AMBest is the table.
Version is the the field in AMbest table.

I need to get the latest version, but my code does not working.  can someone please help me out?

btw, if AMBest is empty, I want to assign a default value 0 for latestVersion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var latestVersion = _db.AMBest.All().Select(_db.AMBest.Version.Max()).ToScalarOrDefault<int>();`